# .NET Core how to properly store user details on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When my user logs in, my server returns 3 items:

1. User Details
2. Tenant Details
3. Jwt Token and Refresh Token

Currently I store these into Redis and it helps to prevent my app from calling the server multiple times in each request.

However, I noticed that if I were to use another web server, I won't be able to securely use Redis.

What are the alternatives to storing the 3 items that are returned from the db?

Here are the examples:

1. User Details

> {"Id":"2ce7112e-14f4-4e45-b645-2f1cdf5abba0","Device":"Other -
> Windows","IP":"::1","UserName":"user@one.com","Name":"User
> One","TenantId":"c224987d-a097-46e2-960b-c8494c9aa643","TenantName":"TOne"}

2. Tenant Details

> {"TenantId":"c224987d-a097-46e2-960b-c8494c9aa643","TenantName":"TOne","TenantBackgroundLink":"link","TenantFirstFontColor":"#000000","TenantSecondFontColor":"#FFFFFF"}

3. Jwt and Refresh Token

> {"SessionToken":"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","RefreshToken":"pS9H99701t1mmrNcm7X2Y3d70IqqzLB"}

Comment: Local storage or session storage depending on your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to hide it from my users? With Redis, I only need to expose 1 key to them.

Comment: Take a look at this; https://dev.to/gkoniaris/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens-51cf

Comment: So store it in a cookie? I guess if thats the only option.

Comment: In memory (own code) or through a http-only cookie is the safest and don't allow the user to (easily) access the information.